# Como cambiar el valor de un span cuando cambie el valor de un label

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un label el cual cambia de valor `<label id="numeroRows2"><b></b></label>` necesito que cuando el valor este label cambie, actualize el valor del mismo en un span,`<span id"spanRows2"></span>`, de momento tengo este script que cambia el valor del span con el del label, pero me falta la validación.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var valorRows2 = document.getElementById('numeroRows2').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("spanRows2").innerHTML=valorRows2;
});
```

Comment: ¿Y que debe ocurrir para que el valor de ese label cambie?  ¿como lo cambias?  Allí donde hagas el cambio es donde debes poner ese código que muestras (pero corrige el **valorRows1**, y pon el **valorRows2** en su lugar)

Comment: Cambia cuando se carga un dato de un xml, necesito alguna validación que detecte que el label cambio y hay poner ese valor al span

Comment: ¿Pero como cargas el XML?  ¿con javascript?  Si es con javascript entonces no te va a costar nada agregar tu código allí justo despues de la carga del XML supongo.